# Conditional load libraries depending on instrumentation

Tags: linker, loader, address-sanitizer

Let's say I have a binary foo and bar. They both link to library baz.
I want to enable ASAN only for the process foo but not for process bar.
I build two version of baz, one with ASAN instrumented (package it in /pkg/asan/lib/) and other without asan (package it in /pkg/lib).

I want process foo to be link/load to libbaz from /pkg/asan/lib/ , but want process bar to link/load the library from /pkg/lib.

Is there anyways at compile time i can specify foo to first check if the library is present in /pkg/asan/lib , if not go then link with the library from /pkg/lib.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyways at compile time i can specify foo to first check if the library is present in /pkg/asan/lib , if not go then link with the library from /pkg/lib.

Sure: when linking `foo` with AddressSanitizer, add `-L/pkg/asan/lib -Wl,-rpath=/pkg/asan/lib` options.